# KeyError at /accounts/signup/ 'sociallogin' when using Django All Auth

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-allauth

After I setup Django All Auth, anytime I click on the SignUp button, it gives me this error:

**KeyError at /accounts/signup/

'sociallogin'**

The Login works fine. I have tried downgrading the AllAuth version, but that did not help. This is my first time using the Django Allauth package. Furthermore, is it compulsory I setup providers (e.g. Google) before I can use the Allauth package?

**Error**

```
KeyError at /accounts/signup/

'sociallogin'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/signup/
Django Version:     3.0.7
Exception Type:     KeyError
Exception Value:    

'sociallogin'

Exception Location:     C:\Users\user1\.virtualenvs\testproject-L2l8zpjO\lib\site-packages\allauth\socialaccount\forms.py in __init__, line 15
Python Executable:  C:\Users\user1\.virtualenvs\testproject-L2l8zpjO\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.8.2
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\Programming stuff\\django\\testproject',
 'C:\\Users\\user1\\.virtualenvs\\testproject-L2l8zpjO\\Scripts\\python38.zip',
 'c:\\python37\\DLLs',
 'c:\\python37\\lib',
 'c:\\python37',
 'C:\\Users\\user1\\.virtualenvs\\testproject-L2l8zpjO',
 'C:\\Users\\user1\\.virtualenvs\\testproject-L2l8zpjO\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**settings.py** (Some lines that I don't think are essential to show have been removed to reduce the amount of code)

```
from decouple import config, Csv
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', cast=bool)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = config('ALLOWED_HOSTS', cast=Csv())

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Default
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    
    # 3rd party
    
    # All Auth
    'allauth', 
    'allauth.account', 
    'allauth.socialaccount', 
    #'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'crispy_forms',

    # Local
    'pages',
    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR), 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

# Custom User
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

SITE_ID = 1

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",

    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'

# Email settings

EMAIL_BACKEND = config('EMAIL_BACKEND')
MAILER_EMAIL_BACKEND = EMAIL_BACKEND  
EMAIL_HOST = config('EMAIL_HOST')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config('EMAIL_HOST_USER')
EMAIL_PORT =  config('EMAIL_PORT', cast=int)  
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True  
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER


# Django All Auth settings
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_EXPIRE_DAYS = 7
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_PASSWORD_ENTER_TWICE = False
ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_ANONYMOUS_REDIRECT_URL = LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION_AUTHENTICATED_REDIRECT_URL  = None
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_LIMIT = 5
ACCOUNT_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS_TIMEOUT = 3600
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_BLACKLIST = ['admin', 'superuser', 'user']

SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
# SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'users.adapter.DisableSocialLoginAdapter'
SOCIALACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'


ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'add_email': 'allauth.account.forms.AddEmailForm',
    'change_password': 'allauth.account.forms.ChangePasswordForm',
    'disconnect': 'allauth.socialaccount.forms.DisconnectForm',
    'login': 'allauth.account.forms.LoginForm',
    'reset_password': 'allauth.account.forms.ResetPasswordForm',
    'reset_password_from_key': 'allauth.account.forms.ResetPasswordKeyForm',
    'set_password': 'allauth.account.forms.SetPasswordForm',
    'signup': 'allauth.account.forms.SignupForm',    
    'signup': 'allauth.socialaccount.forms.SignupForm',
}

# 'signup': 'allauth.account.forms.SignupForm'
```

I am also using a Custom User model inheriting from AbstractBaseUser.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Having encountered the same error, this is what fixed it for me:

In forms.py

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from allauth.socialaccount.forms import SignupForm as SocialSignupForm
```

Because I was also importing `SignupForm` from `allauth.account.forms`, I think there may have been a conflict with the `SignupForm` from `allauth.socialaccount.forms`. To remedy this, I imported it **as** `SocialSignupForm` to create the distinction.

```
class MyCustomSocialSignupForm(SocialSignupForm):

    def save(self, request):
```

Additionally, rather than declaring all of my custom forms under `ACCOUNT_FORMS = {}`, I placed my custom social form under `SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {}` like so:

```
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    'signup': 'accounts.forms.MyCustomSignupForm'
}

SOCIALACCOUNT_FORMS = {
   'signup': 'accounts.forms.MyCustomSocialSignupForm'
}
```